# Is there memory latency checker for Ubuntu 22.04 on M1 chip?

Tags: 22.04, ram, arm64

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS as a virtual machine on my MacBook with an M1 chip. Is there any memory latency checker for it? I tried Intel memory latency checker, but it needs msr-tools which doesn't support M1 chip.